# Char * Array Memory Allocation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Lets say below is my char pointer array:

```
char *names[4] = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   cout << &names[i] << endl;
}
```

This will print 4 memory allocations:

```
0x7fff591c9b90
0x7fff591c9b98
0x7fff591c9ba0
0x7fff591c9ba8
```

My Question is why is it allocating 8 bytes for each element in the array? Can you help me in understanding how memory is allocated for each data type in C++? like for Char *, char, in, int *, string, etc., or quote any reference.

TIA

Comment: Concerning the internal structures of C++, consider "The Design and Evolution of C++".

Comment: Aside: the array should be `const char* names[4]`.

Comment: Because `names` is an array of pointers, and `names[i]` is a pointer, not a string literal.  Presumably your implementation (compiler and host system) is 64 bits.  Assuming 8 bit characters (reasonably common) that means `sizeof` yields `8` for pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Question is why is it allocating 8 bytes for each element in the
>   array?

Well probably because size of pointer on your machine is 8 bytes. It is common that size of pointer is 8 bytes on 64 bit systems. But again there is no hard rule for this and size of pointers may vary per machine. And since each element of your array is a pointer, hence the result.

Memory allocation say for `int` is different from `int*` in that in the former you need to allocate space which will hold all values of integer, while in the latter, you need as much space to contain value of a pointer.

Comment: This is new. Can you tell me how can I check how my compiler is allocating size to pointers? I want to test this on a 32 bit machine as well.

Comment: @Spark Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: @Spark in your question, you have a program that prints addresses of consequtive pointers. That effectively exactly what you just asked for: a way to check how much memory your compiler allocates for pointers.

Comment: @Giorgi Is there any command line argument to check how much memory is allocated to a pointer on my machine?
Sorry if my question is Naive. I'm all new to programming

Comment: @Spark Not sure but what you have in code is one way to tell the size of a char pointer

Comment: It is usually in compiler documentation.   Computing `sizeof (void *)` or `sizeof` for any pointer type (other than pointers to members or pointers to functions) will also normally do it in code.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal is an array of read-only `char` elements, terminated by the special character`'\0'`. When you use a string literal it decays to a *pointer* to the first element in that array. So making an array of four *pointers* to `char` will always have the element size be the size of a pointer, even if that pointer is to a string literal.

On 64 bit systems the usual size of a pointer is 64 bits, i.e. 8 bytes. That's why each element in the array is 8 bytes. On a 32 bit system, the size of pointers are of course 32 bits, 4 bytes.

The length of the string literals doesn't matter, for example take

```
char const* string_array[] = { "a", "bc", "def", "ghij" };
```

In the above array the element size will *still* be the size of the pointer, i.e. 8 bytes on a 64 bit system.